# Issues with VPN on Android Wifi Hotspot using on Laptop

Tags: android

I am connected to my **offshore vessel** 's satellite network which has limited website access. So I use VPN on Android to access all websites and create a hotspot on Android to use VPN protected internet on my laptop.

Now a certain bank related KYC process requires me to share my location (GPS & IP based) which is expected to be in India where I am not currently based.
GPS location I was able to spoof using the Fake GPS Android app.
For IP, I connected to an Indian VPN server, and on my phone it shows an Indian IP location.
However, when I connect my phone to my laptop with VPN active, my laptop IP location is still the one without VPN (Netherlands).

How can I get the IP location of my laptop to be the same as my phone?

Comment: VPN sharing AFAIK doesn't work on stock devices:  https://android.stackexchange.com/q/216033/2241

Comment: Use the VPN from your computer, not on android.